# Convert selenium vba code to xmlhttp get request

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, xmlhttprequest

I have the following code that I used selenium VBA but as I am trying to improve my skills, I am trying to use GET method but as for this link I am totally lost
Here's the code used in selenium

```
Private bot As New Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub Test()
Dim ws          As Worksheet
Dim c           As Range
Dim dlg         As alert

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

For Each c In ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    With bot
        If c.Row = 2 Then
            .Get "https://www.moi.gov.kw/gdt/Service_Paymnt.html"
            On Error GoTo Skipper
            .SwitchToFrame "Services"
        ElseIf c.Row > 2 Then
            .FindElementById("openNewSearch").Click
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
            On Error GoTo Skipper
        End If

        .FindElementByXPath("//input[@type='text'][@name='numberValue']").SendKeys c.Value
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
        .FindElementByXPath("//*[@name='search']").Click
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:04")

        c.Offset(, 1).Value = Replace(Replace(Replace(Split(.FindElementByXPath("/html[1]/body[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/form[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[2]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[1]/td[1]").Text)(0), vbCrLf, ""), Chr(34), ""), vbLf, "")
    End With
Next c

Exit Sub

Skipper:
On Error Resume Next
    Set dlg = bot.SwitchToAlert(Raise:=False)
    dlg.Dismiss
On Error GoTo 0
Resume
End Sub
```

An example of the numbers used "290123101619" 
Hope I can find a way using XMLHTTP GET ..
The problem is that the URL I found in the Netwrok is too long and when copy that url and test to see if it is working on the browser or not, I found it doesn't return the DOC result.

Comment: Page won't load for me - even under different locations.

Comment: The website is only working for Kuwait. I even tried to open it from my country Egypt but I couldn't .. so I used a device of one my friend using teamviewer to be able to login the website. I thought using VPN may solve this problem but it doesn't.

Comment: when you manually enter the number and submit do you observe a POST request in the network traffic?

Comment: No I noticed GET and when tried to copy the URL that has the parameters (including the number I am searching for), the page doesn't open for the desired output

Comment: with xmlhttp does it return the expected content when  .Open "GET", urlWithParams, False  ?

Comment: No it just opens the main page with the search box and doesn't return the desired content

Comment: Did you set the appropriate headers?

Comment: What is the headers that I should put? Can you give me example and I will try to adapt it later.

Comment: Headers are shown in the dev tools of browser for the GET request

Comment: Do you mean response headers or request headers?

Comment: Request headers